# grep + search recursive complex syntax under folder in files/scripts

Tags: linux, awk, grep, rhel, perl

We want to search the following line recursive under folder/s

```
awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'port is up' -e 'valid output'
```

so we did that:

```
grep -r "awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'port is up' -e 'valid output'"  /var
grep -r "awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'port is up' -e 'valid output'"  /etc
grep -r "awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'port is up' -e 'valid output'"  /opt
```

but I am not sure if grep can managed the " ' " and "{" characters
or maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the `awk` program you're searching for? It's just passing on its input... Ah well, you want the `-F` option for `grep` to search for a fixed string, and possibly `-x` to force a whole line match. What `grep` implementation are you using? GNU `grep` I presume?

Comment: yes I am sure that we need to search the awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'port is up' -e 'valid output'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for a fixed string (not a regular expression), use the `-F` option with `grep`.  If you additionally need to make sure that your string matches an *entire* line, use `-x`:

```
grep -Fx -r '...your string here...' directory
```

To get approximate hits (if a full line search doesn't return anything), I would start with just `port is up` (without `-x`), or possibly

```
grep -F -r -e 'port is up' -e 'valid output' directory
```

Neither `|` nor `{` or `}` are special in a regular expression pattern when you're using basic regular expression as you do here. `'` is never special in a regular expression.  However, since you are searching with a *string* (not a pattern), you should nonetheless use `-F`.